# Graphs update only when I write enter() at the end

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I tried to toggle the data using
d3.interval and render the data as bar graphs on my svg.

As below.

interval--

```
d3.interval(function(){update(data);
                       flag =! flag;
                      },1000)
```

rendering--

```
function update(input){
    
    var value = flag ? 'revenue':'profit'


    x.domain(input.map(function(d){return d.month}));
    y.domain([0,d3.max(input, function(d){return d[value]})])

    var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);
    var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d){return '$'+d})
    
    xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall.tickSizeOuter(0))
    yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall.tickSizeOuter(0))

    var rects = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)

    rects.exit().remove()


    
    rects.enter().append('rect').attr('y', (d)=>{return height-y.range([0,height])(d[value])})
                 .attr('x', (d)=>{ return 50+x(d.month)})
                 .attr('height',(d)=>{return y(d[value])})
                 .attr('width',x.bandwidth())
                 .attr('fill','grey')
                 
    }
```

However,
it doesn't toggle the graph depending on the data fed into the rectangles.
It only worked when I put .append() at the end of rectangle rendering like below.

```
rects.attr('y', (d)=>{return height-y.range([0,height])(d[value])})
             .attr('x', (d)=>{ return 50+x(d.month)})
             .attr('height',(d)=>{return y(d[value])})
             .attr('width',x.bandwidth())
             .attr('fill','grey')
             .enter().append('rect')
```

Why is it that I need to add enter and append at the end?
The reason that I don't get this is
Even if I put the .enter().append('rect') at the beginning,
the properties of the rect can be redefined and updated.

However, the properties of the rectangles weren't updated once I put the enter() argument beforehand.

I tested out by adding 'console.log' like below.

```
rects.enter().append('rect').attr('fill',function(){return flag? "rgba(100,0,0,0.2)":'rgba(0,100,0,0.2)'}).attr('y', (d)=>{return height-y.range([0,height])(d[value])})
             .attr('x', (d)=>{ return 50+x(d.month)})
             .attr('height',(d)=>{console.log(d[value])
                                  ;return y(d[value])})
             .attr('width',x.bandwidth())
```

It doesn't log anything, it logs only when I put enter at the end.

Why all the arguments don't run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case you have an *enter* selection but nothing changing your update selection. In your second case you're changing your *update* selection while doing nothing to your enter selection.

Write your *update* and *enter* selections clearly and separately. This normally leads to duplicated code... if you don't like those duplications, use [`merge()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge):

```
var rects = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)

rects.exit().remove()

rects = rects.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('fill', 'grey')
  .merge(rects)
  .attr('y', (d) => {
    return height - y.range([0, height])(d[value])
  })
  .attr('x', (d) => {
    return 50 + x(d.month)
  })
  .attr('height', (d) => {
    return y(d[value])
  })
  .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
```

Answer (score 1):

D3 uses the data join, which doens't act on elements directly, but describes their transformations. When you do:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
```

you're not selecting all the rectangles, but only those in the "update" selection. [Here's a more detailled explaination by the author of D3.](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

Nowadays, it's recommended to use the [`selection.join()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) method which makes selection-based code clearer:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .join(
    enter => enter.append('rect')
      .attr('fill', 'grey'),
    update => update
      .attr('x', (d) => 50 + x(d.month))
      .attr('y', (d) => height-y.range([0,height])(d[value]))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', (d) => y(d[value])),
    exit => exit.remove()
   )
```